# How to activate docking views in Eclipse e4 application?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I'm new to Eclipse RCP applications. I'd like to create an application with views that can be docked, minimized, dragged, etc, like in the Eclipse IDE.

Using Eclipse Luna on Mac OS X with e4 tools 0.17, I've created a first application by New Project -> Eclipse 4 Application Project. If I create a Part Stack, the parts show as tabs, but these cannot be dragged and docked.

What do I have to do to activate the docking framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon` to the Add-ons section of your Application.e4xmi

Comment: Thanks! This works. More precisely, you have to: 1) add `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt` as dependency and 2) specify `bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon`as an add-on